# MS Graph API - MS Teams channel last updated/last message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

we want to do a report of all our Teams and Channels.

With that it would be nice to get when it was lastly updated/used so we could do some cleanup afterwards.

Via Powershell and also GraphaAPI check i know that channels do not save data of when they have been lastly updated, the only chance I have is to use GraphAPI and check messages for similar data.

This call [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages) should help me out BUT it always returns with 403. I have all needed permissions consented (as I am global admin in our tenant), I have correct ID's added (checked with checking the channel and returning details of the channel). Request token is valid.

[Graph Explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmnmF.png)

MS Teams API export is one of the possible option but since I need to check way long in the past, it is limited by retention policy. I really just need to get last message (not the text, but just details about it) from each channel to get a "time stamp" of last activity.

Ideally when and who.

Can you please help me out?
Thank you